# derivative is bounded $\iff$ functions is lipstchitz

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

I need to prove the theorem that says that, if the derivative of a function is bounded, then the function itself is lipstchitz continuous. I'm concerned about the $\leftarrow$ part of my proof.

$\leftarrow$

If $|f'(x)| \le c$, we have by the mean value theorem:

$$\exists d\in [x,y] / f(y)-f(x) = f'(d)(y-x)\rightarrow$$

$$|f(y)-f(x)| = |f'(d)||(y-x)|\le c|(y-x)|$$

$\rightarrow$

If $|f(x)-f(y)|\le c|x-y|$ for all $x,y$, we must prove that $|f'(z)|\le c$ for all $z$. 
That's what I did:

$$f'(x) = \lim_{x\to y} \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\le \lim_{x\to y} \left|\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\right| = \lim_{x\to y}\frac{|f(y)-f(x)|}{|y-x|}\le c$$

is it right?

Comment: Your argument shows that $|f'(x)|\le c$ for each $x$ where $f'(x)$ exists. But the function $f(x)=|x|$ shows that Lipschitz alone is not enough to guarantee that $f'(x)$ exists for all $x$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins the proof is just for the intervals where $f$ is differentiable... So does my proof work?

Comment: Yes: $|f'(x)|=\lim_{y\to x}\Big|{f(y)-f(x)\over y-x}\Big|=\lim_{y\to x}{|f(y)-f(x)\over|y-x|}\le c$.